# A nice way to let user select a number of year/month/day, and how to save into database

Tags: selection

I want to let my user select a number and a time unit to set a limit time.

This is the first design.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH8Xur.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I'm decide save data by this way, but is there any better design for UX?

Comment: Never let the architecture of the database depend on how thing are shown/operated in the UI and vice versa. One day you will regret it when one of them has to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for two or three fixed options I prefer to have a single selectButton, like the one below:

[image]

If there are around 10 items for selection, a single dropdown would be useful, like the example you put.

For more than 10 items I would suggest a search and select dropdown.

[image]

PS: I know this is not the channel for DB discussions, but in your table I would store a numeric value, representing an Enumerator rather than the text of the value. So, it would be 1 for Days, 2 for Months, 3 for Years, etc.